# Q:SQLzoo JOIN question #13 multiple cols following GROUP BY

Tags: mysql, sql

Hi I've been working on the SQLzoo questions and I'm confused about why certain cols needs to be placed after GROUP BY when 2 tables are joined.

The questions is to list every match with the goals scored by each team, fetch data from 2 tables, game and goal.

The correct answer should be:

```
SELECT game.mdate, 
              game.team1,
              SUM(CASE WHEN goal.teamid=game.team1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS score1,
              game.team2,
              SUM(CASE WHEN goal.teamid=game.team2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS score2
FROM game LEFT JOIN goal ON goal.matchid = game.id
GROUP BY game.id
ORDER BY game.mdate, goal.matchid, game.team1, game.team2
```

But when I change the GROUP BY phrase to [GROUP BY goal.matchid] or [GROUP BY mdate] the answer is wrong.
It's also correct when GROUP BY is followed by [game.mdate, game.team1, game.team2].

Would appreciate if anyone can explain why is it!

Answer (score 1):

In SQL, you always apply aggregation to all other columns apart from your group by columns.

For example: In your case, you have used 'mdate', 'team1', 'team2' in your select statement without any aggregation so you must specify those columns in your group by clause.
OR
If you use only 'mdate' in group by clause then all others columns in select list (except 'mdate') must be aggregated.

Hope this answers your question.

Comment: Thank you! This definitely explains why [game.mdate, game.team1, game.team2] will do the job. But I'm still confused how [GROUP BY game.id] also works.

Comment: Ideally it shouldn't work. In my case it isn't working. I have created two tables  (goal & game) in SQL Server by taking reference from this link (https://sqlzoo.net/wiki/JOIN_Quiz). When I tried to run your query (with  [GROUP BY game.id] only ), it's giving me the error (which is what expected is): `Error: Column 'game.mdate' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.`

Comment: That's so weird I tried it on different devices and [game.id] all worked...but I'll keep trying figure out this and update once I got it. Thanks again!

Comment: I have created the same tables (game and goal) and run the same query you written above and got the error. You can check it on this link: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=777e3f98017415933468dbda60daef3b    _Please let me know if you find any mistake here_